Why does YouTube Data API still return hiddenSubscriberCount: true for some channels, even though YouTube deprecated this?
I am using the YouTube Data API to retrieve channel statistics. For some channels, the hiddenSubscriberCount is still set to true, even though YouTube has deprecated this feature. This makes it impossible for me to get the actual subscriber count from the API.
For example, the channel with ID UCvgcGr2ebkkgOYO0BLeDj6Q shows hiddenSubscriberCount: true in the API response. However, when I visit the channel on the YouTube website or app, I can see the subscriber count without any issue.
How is it still possible for this value to be true, and is there any way to get the actual subscriber count using the API?
